# Should I write classes for WPF controls?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid which I call let's say `FooHistory`. Now I need plenty of functionality related to that so I go ahead and I create a `FooHistory` class. Now I have a `FooHistory` class and a control.

In my `MainWindow` constructor I create a new instance of this class and pass the instance of `this` (i.e. the `MainWindow`) to the `FooHistory` class sort of like dependency injection. Then later when the `FooHistory` class wants to interact with the `FooHistory` control, I do things like `this.mainWindow.FooHistory.Items.Add(...)`.

My question is that is this the recommended way to write WPF applications or am I missing some fundamental approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use for our programs the MVVM approach. While the details may differ from program to program MVVM is usually build with 3 main parts.

**Model:**
This is you data object. This may be business data like

```
class Account
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    string Address {get;set;
}
```

but can also be UI data like:

```
class Window
{
    Point Position {get;set;}
    Size Size {get;set;}
}
```

These objects are for holding data, nothing more. No events, no commands no methods (Thats one point where different interpretation of MVVM differ).

**ViewModel:**
This is to wrap the model and provide logic around the underlying model. This class is also used to convert a business model property into a view understandable property.

```
class AccountViewModel
{
    public AccountViewModel(Account aWrappedModel)
    {
    }

    string Name {get {return Model.Name;} }

    AddressObject Address { get{ return new AddressObject( Model.Address ); }
}
```

**View:**

Is the wpf part this can be user controls, custom controls, windows, datatemplates etc.
Despite a common believe, its fine to have code behind for view otherwise you have to bend over backwords just because you heard that the view isn't allowed to have code.

The usual approach now is to create a model, one or more viewmodels and set these viewmodels as `DataContext` in your view. Sometimes you need a DataTemplate to display the given data, like a DataTemplate for our AccountViewModel.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type AccountViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}/>
        <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveAccount}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This design makes heavy use of Databinding which is fundamental for MVVM and works quite nicely. Of course a couple of problems can arise like: How to handle Collection with models? How to handle events in the viewmodels coming from the ui? How to store my data?

But for these you find many resources here and in the web. But this answer should give you a rough overview of how i and alot other people work with WPF.

Answer (score 1):

if most of your functionality is presentation-logic,
you can create a user control (by subclassing UserControl), and have a pair of .xaml and .xaml.cs files,
and put your presentation logic in the .xaml.cs file.

if most of the FooHistory class functionality is business-logic (or anything other than presentation), it's worthwhile to separate the FooHistory control from the FooHistory class, but in this case perhaps it's better to define an interface for the control, and pass the FooHistory instsance a reference to the control using this interface.
this way your FooHistory class needn't know anything about presentation - doesn't even need to know that it's WPF.

if you can avoid passing a tree of controls (such as SomeWindow.ParentControl.ChildControl.Items), it would make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

What you've described sounds like some kind of Model-View-Presenter pattern, a variant of MVC. As it is definitely a good pattern, especially for ASP.NET and WinForms, it doesn't utilise some core concepts of WPF.

Things you're missing are called **Data Binding** and Commands. On top of that features a new variant of MVC evolved - **Model-View-ViewModel** (MVVM), sometimes called Presentation Model. Roughly explained:
Your Window is called a View.
Youd Busines Logic is encapsulated in a Model.
You create a ViewModel class that exposes some properties which are View-specific representation of the Model. VM should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to provide a way of notifying the UI about data changes. You expose operations the same way - by a property of type `ICommand`.
In View's constructor you write something like `this.DataContext = new ViewModel()`
Then you bind your View controls properties and ViewModel using `{Binding PropName}` syntax.

You might also want to check out some frameworks for MVVM like **Prism**, **MVVM Light**.

Here is some sample: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/

Comment: Interesting, can you point me to some place for a tutorial/article that shows a tiny sample application made with MVVM in mind?

Comment: I added some sample that seems to be good for me but I've never tried to learn this way so I don't guarantee. I would start just with the framework documentation. There is allways a 'Getting started' page or simmilar.

Comment: @rFactor: This is a good place to start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can...... but there is no need to do that...........
the alternative way is.........

Make a dataset of data used in your grid......then import that whole dataset into your grid. so here no need to add items.....  now you can filter,sort, add,remove or anything you want....